# Why non anonymous function is not fired on window resize?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I want to bind/unbind event listener to window resize I am using the `.on()`/`.off()` functions to do it, because `.off()` require to pass the same function as in `.on()` I created a separate function which is passed in both places.

Here is the code (not working):

```
var i = 0;
function onResizeListener(){
    $('#debug').html(i);
    i++;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize',onResizeListener());
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eRupC/2/

This one is working: http://jsfiddle.net/eRupC/1/ when I wrap the `onResizeListener()` with an anonymous function.

The desirable result in the example: When you resize your window the number has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you need to pass something to `onResizeListener`. If not, remove the parenthesis from onResizeListener as the the other answers say. [Bind Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = 2;
  var y = 4;
  $(window).bind('resize', function() {
    onResizeListener(x, y);
  });
});
```

This would also work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    onResizeListener();
  });
});
```

To [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the function call from the resize event but still pass parameters to the function you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //bind
    $(window).bind('resize', { foo: 'bar' },onResizeListener);

    //unbind, wrap in event you wish to use to unbind it
    $(window).unbind('click', onResizeListener);
});
```

Comment: how to pass them parameters to that onResizeListener function?

Comment: Just like you would normally with a function. See my addition to the first example in my answer.

Comment: then how to unbind the anonymous function? :)

Comment: You can unbind `onResizeListener()` from the scroll event. Added another example to my answer.

Comment: I believe this should not work, since it's another anonymous function, but I would accept your answer, because the original question was different :). See the not working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pc5uC/1/

Comment: @NikChankov Sorry you are correct. I modified the final example. Here it is working. http://jsfiddle.net/pc5uC/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the brackets from the event handler code...

```
var i = 0;
function onResizeListener(){
    $('#debug').html(i);
    i++;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize',onResizeListener);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
  $(window).on('resize',onResizeListener());
```

with this

```
  $(window).on('resize',onResizeListener);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pc5uC/